# "…my great pictures…to paint some great moral of the heart..."

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following is a quote by [William Etty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Etty), the author of *The Sirens and Ulysses*, a very large painting (3m by 4.5m or 9.75ft by 14.5ft). It was taken from [the Wikipedia article of the painting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sirens_and_Ulysses):

> My aim in all my great pictures has been to paint some great moral on the heart ... the importance of resisting SENSUAL DELIGHTS <sub>[sic]</sub>.

It seems that he wanted to depict great moral in his works, which, in this case, are resistance to sensual delights and *The Sirens and Ulysses*.

However, what does "great pictures" mean? Are he saying that his paintings ("pictures") are "great" in size? Or are their meanings "great"? Or does this refer to an imaginary scene(s) that he "pictured" his mind while/before working on the painting(s)?

Comment: The links you provide indicate that Etty was known for painting very large canvases, so presumably 'great' is a reference to that rather than a claim to artistic greatness.

Comment: What @KateBunting said. Except of course *within the very same sentence* Etty also uses ***great*** to mean ***considerable, important, illustrious,...*** I imagine the context was "unrehearsed speech", since that would be a lamentable thing to do in any serious written context. Don't copy it.

Comment: Great could mean finished paintings, not sketches and studies.

Comment: @YosefBaskin: No. Unquestionably the first"great" *literally* refers to physical size, whereas the second is a metaphorical *intensifying* usage (a great moral is a ***high, lofty, noble** moral*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - A big picture paints a big moral on the heart? I don't know that Etty's main purpose was to inscribe morals on peoples' hearts. The first description I had of him was of a purveyor of 'respectable' soft-core porn (as we would say nowadays) to prosperous Victorians. I have to say that I decided to delete a Windows desktop wallpaper I had of a well-known painting by John William Waterhouse.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Well, [there it is in black and white.](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/the_eclectic_review/NOkEAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22aim+in+all+my+great+pictures+has+been+to+paint+some+great%22&pg=PA665&printsec=frontcover) Don't ask me why that *particular* link is to *the eclectic review* in lower case. (I don't think they were early adopters of the *e e cummings* orthographic style! :)

Comment: This can be simply answered with "William Etty 1789-1849"  Anything that is more than 150 years old can be considered archaic and not relevant to modern idiom.  The first "great" probably just means "big" in the idiom of 1800.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I think Etty's remarks about the moral quality of his own works, as the following paragraph hints (in that page you linked to), are rather like the stern injunction 'Strictly for art lovers only' that used to be on the covers of books of photographs sold in certain shops in Soho and the Charing Cross Road

Comment: I didn't know of Etty, but "my great pictures ... some great moral" speaks to me about conceit. Deeply religious people are no less free of that vice than secular.

Comment: @JamesK I need to translate this quote. I know that it is archaic.

Comment: "I need to translate"... hence you are using English, not learning English. As such this would be better on [english.se]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question of English usage is about translation of a pre 1850 quote, and not about learning modern English.  English usage questions are more likely to be answered on [english.se]

Comment: @JamesK In that case, do I have to move this post there?

Comment: The question (in my view) is perfectly fine where it is now. That you need to translate the quote in your mother tongue shouldn't influence users in the slightest. @JamesK  The question is asking about the meaning of a single word written in 19th century, it's hardly archaic, and it's helpful to reiterate that words have multiple meanings and often meanings are subject to change or shifting.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The original source (linked in my answer) used "on the heart". Also, I took the quote from the Wikipedia article of *The Sirens and Ulysses*.

Comment: As you are the author of the question and the answer, you can edit and rollback the edit or just replace "of" with "on". For me, the meaning "paint some great moral on the heart" made less sense than "of the heart". I confess I hadn't read the quote in the Wikipedia article. My apology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that he did mean "large paintings". The quote originates from [Volume 11 of The Art Journal, 1849](https://archive.org/details/sim_art-journal-us_1849-02-01_11/page/n3/mode/2up?q=%22My%20aim%20in%20all%20my%20great%22) (emphasis mine):

> My aim in all my great pictures has been to paint some great moral on the heart [...] these, in all, make nine **colossal** pictures, as it was my desire to paint three times three.

Thanks to @FumbleFingers for providing [a link to *The Eclectic Review*](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/the_eclectic_review/NOkEAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22aim%20in%20all%20my%20great%20pictures%20has%20been%20to%20paint%20some%20great%22&pg=PA665&printsec=frontcover), from which I could trace back to the original source.

Comment: There's probably a correlation between size and importance because especially before about 1850, at a time when large-scale history painting was considered the most elevated genre of art, significant paintings on major themes would be large.